# "this" en método anidado de Class extends ¿Cómo accedo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, método, this

Me da un error con el "this" que hay dentro del método anidado. He investigado lo de "super" pero no entiendo cómo aplicarlo.

```
class Ventana extends Tabla {
  anim() {
    setInterval(function () {
      this.x--;
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Aparte del problema del ámbito de la variable `this`, tienes un error de sintaxis en tu código, te falta un cierre de paréntesis y además te falta el valor en milisegundos como segundo parámetro del `setInterval`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por mencionarlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso se debe a que las funciones declaradas con `function` crean su propio contexto y en ese caso `this` hace referencia a lo que existe dentro de la función y no al objeto de la clase.

Eso se puede solucionar usando una función de flecha:

```
class Ventana extends Tabla {
      anim() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.x--;
        };
      };
 };
```

[Documentación this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Aparte del problema que aclaras con tu excelente respuesta, el código tiene un error de sintaxis, le estaba comentado eso precisamente al OP, falta el cierre de un paréntesis y falta el valor en milisegundos para el `setInterval` (a menos que el OP haya implementado su propia función `setInterval`). Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pensé que nunca me iban ha hacer falta las funciones flecha!